# I need to edit the generic class Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I need to change this generic class that accepts an array to something that is not an array

```
class GenericDataSource<T> : NSObject {
    var data: DynamicValue<[T]> = DynamicValue([])
    //var data: DynamicValue<T>?
}
```

When I remove the square brackets I get an error

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (() -> Void)

class DynamicValue<T> {
    
    var value : T {
        didSet {
            self.notify()
        }
    }
    
    private var observers = [String: CompletionHandler]()
    
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    public func addObserver(_ observer: NSObject, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        observers[observer.description] = completionHandler
    }
    
    public func addAndNotify(observer: NSObject, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        self.addObserver(observer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        self.notify()
    }
    
    private func notify() {
        observers.forEach({ $0.value() })
    }
    
    deinit {
        observers.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `NSObject` in Swift unless absolutely necessary. It's an Obj-C legacy type that should only be used for Obj-C interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

You need an init in `GenericDataSource`

```
class GenericDataSource<T> {
    var data: DynamicValue<T>

    init(_ value: T) {
        data = DynamicValue(value)
    }
}
```

or make `data` optional

```
class GenericDataSource<T> : NSObject {
    var data: DynamicValue<T>?
}
```

And then use them like

```
let gds = GenericDataSource("Hello")
```

or for the optional variant

```
let gds = GenericDataSource<String>()
gds.data = DynamicValue("Hello")
```

Comment: No need for the `NSObject` inheritance.

Comment: @DávidPásztor It was there in the question and I assumed the GenericDataSource contains more code than this so I kept it but I guess for this answer it isn't relevant